# Is there a way to pass a Viewbag object from Mvc to a webforms usercontrol codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I am mixing Mvc and webforms and want to pass a Mvc Viewbag object to a webforms usercontrol which didn't work with my approach, shown below.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Views/Shared/_LengthsAndColors.ascx" TagPrefix="cc1" TagName="_LengthsAndColors" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<cc1:_LengthsAndColors runat="server" Source="<%= ViewBag.Source %>" ID="_LengthsAndColors1" />
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That won't work, no...

Apart from the fact that I think mixing MVC and ASP.NET WebForms is a horrible idea, what you could do is serialize the ViewBag to XML or JSON and pass that as a querystring parameter to your user control.

You may want to encrypt or Base64-encode it to not make it too vulnerable to hacking, though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Roy. However, can you please illustrate what you are saying with a short code?